# Which TextView was clicked?

Tags: android, textview

I have 3 TextView fields. How can I track which was clicked? I should do the same thing in all the 3 case. I have tried `onClickListener`, but I think it is not good for this purpose.

Comment: Yes you need an onClickListener or your app will never know a TextView was clicked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your Activity implement a "View" OnClickListener then add the following unimplemented method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.first_id:
        //Does something when this view is clicked...
        break;
    case R.id.second_id:
        //Does something when this view is clicked...
        break;
    case R.id.third_id:
        //Does something when this view is clicked...
        break;
    }
}
```

Then in the onCreate of your Activity make sure to set the OnClickListener for each view.

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_id);
mTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Considering how your question shows a lack of experience with Android I am guessing you will have a few more issues but this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: @KovácsÁkos everyone starts out that way. :)